# Smbus-device emulation in QEMU

Tags: qemu, i2c, smbus

I want to emulate a SMBus/I2C device in QEMU. I see that there are existing modules in QEMU which have SMBus functionality, but I don't know how to create a new one or the command to use the existing one. Can somebody please help here.

Comment: I think you need `-device ipmi-bmc-sim`, `-device ipmi-bmc-extern` or `-device isa-ipmi-kcs`.

Comment: @nevilad can you please tell me how can I use the ipmi-bmc-sim device to send a SMBUs/i2c command from the Guest?

Comment: No, I've didn't used it.